# Two DataGridViews, joined by one to many relation - best practise

Tags: c#, datagridview, .net-3.5

I have 2 datagridviews.

First is displaying "parent table" rows (lets say tOrders).

Second displays "child table" rows (lets say tOrdersItems).

I want to use these DataGridViews for reading and writing data.

1. How should i handle these 2 datagrids? I mean how to show in second DataGridView only rows related with row selected in first datagridview? Shall i use filters or something else?
2. Can I find somewhere article or tutorial about handling related DataGridViews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1:  Basically, you use the DataSource attribute of the DataGridView

2:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8c0cxey.aspx

Comment: The trick is setting the detail BindingSource.DataSource to the master BindingSource so changing the master.Current changes the detail results automatically. Thanks!